# Aurora: Unknown schema in docker parameters

Tags: docker, mesos, apache-aurora

I have an aurora file which contains this docker parameters:

```
jobs = [
  Service(cluster = 'mesos-fr',
      environment = 'devel',
      role = 'root',
      instances = 1,
      name = 'frontend_service',
      task = run_frontend_service,
      container=Docker(image='frontend_service', parameters=[{'name': 'frontend_service'}, {'publish': '{{thermos.ports[http]}}:3000'}])
  )
]
```

Got this error:

```
Error loading configuration: Unknown schema attribute publish
```

Is there a solution for connecting the host port with a docker container port?

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Mustache variable replacements might not help since they happen after the container comes up.

It looks like there's a problem with the form of your Docker Parameters. An example of correct ones is `container=Docker(image='nginx', parameters=[Parameter(name='env',  value='HTTP_PORT={{thermos.ports[http]}')])`.

There is a `Parameter` object, with `name` and `value`. Value can be a string with mustache variable (like ports) so you can throw that stuff in there.

This documentation (under Announcer Objects) might help too: http://aurora.apache.org/documentation/latest/reference/configuration/

Comment: Any chance you could explain this bit "EDIT: Mustache variable replacements might not help since they happen after the container comes up." a bit more? Seems like you mean you can't use `{{}}` replacements in Docker parameters with Aurora because they don't get replaced properly?